# Overfitting with diagonal matrix of covariances

Tags: discriminant-analysis, overfitting

Sample is a realisation of vector of random variables, each variable ~ $\mathcal N$.

The number of samples is small, the length of sample is big.

I would like to perform one-class LDA (linear discriminant), interested only in outliers, but even usage of diagonal matrix of covariance seems to be an overfitting - number of estimated parameters is bigger than number of samples.

Is it the case? What can be done in order to find outliers of large multivariate normal distribution and small amount of samples for estimation of parameters?

I guess further regularization (after diagonalization of matrix) is useless. Could you please give some ideas how to prevent overfitting even before train/test check, only based on number of estimated parameters?

=======

finally found the answer [here](http://compdiag.molgen.mpg.de/ngfn/docs/2005/mar/markowetz-svm.pdf) (if somebody will be interested in this problem).